# Serve mail for multiple domains on a single server?

Tags: email, postfix, domain

I am running a Debian Jessie 8.1 server with a functioning postfix, dovecot, and suirrelmail/rainloop. I have multiple domains on the server. The main server domain is set via example.com.vhost because it is configured with ispconfig3. However, each additional domain is configured through `/etc/apache2/sites-available/another.com.conf`

I have configured the main domain to serve as a `catch-all` by editing `/etc/postfix/virtual` with:

```
@example.com myuser
info@example.com  info
```

Then I update postifx with:

```
nano /etc/postfix/main.cf
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
postmap /etc/postfix/virtual
service postfix reload
```

Question is, as I have said, there are other virtual domains on the server. How can I make them all catch-all to their respective `info@another.com` or at least to the main `info@example.com` email?

I did try adding to `/etc/postfix/virtual` something like `@another.com info` but it did not help. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you run `postmap` on `/etc/postfix/virtual` after changing it?

Comment: Yes, i did. It should work in that way?

Comment: Sound right to me, but I'm not familiar with ispconfig and don't know how it interacts with postfix.  What's the output of `postconf mydestination`? (feel free to censor for additional privacy)

Comment: Following my above example, the main domain is `example.com` and the other hosted domain (`another.com`) is not showing in the output of postconf mydestination: `mydestination = example.com, localhost.com, , localhost`

Comment: Try adding your other domains to the `virtual_alias_domains` parameter and reload postfix.  You may have to remove your `example.com` domain from `mydestination`.

Comment: I do not have `virtual_alias_domains` in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

Comment: @tarleb, thanks that was it. I was missing `virtual_alias_domains`. Once I added it, restarted/reloaded postfix it worked. Any idea how to configure catch-all for all the virtual domains in a single line?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what exactly you mean by "catch-all" here, could you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to fix this:

1. Add mappings for all virtual domains to `/etc/postfix/virtual`.  Postfix will accept a message if any entry in that file matches.
2. Setting `virtual_alias_domains` to the list of other domains you want to receive mail for.  You can then use a regexp table `virtual_alias_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/virtual.pcre` where the latter contains something like `/.*/ info`.

Beware: This is untested.